# Apply percentage coupon to entire order (Commerce)

Tags: rules, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce and Commerce Coupon Percentage. It works great for most products. However, I have a product priced at $0 and the price is then altered through rules which changes the line item total for that order.

Because the product is priced at $0, the percentage does not apply. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to apply the percentage coupon to the entire order rather than the product price. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Price calculation in Drupal Commerce always happens at a line item level. There are order level coupons for knocking a set amount off an order total, but we treat percentage coupons as these line item level price calculations. You should be able to adjust the weight of your product pricing rules so your rule that updates the price gets evaluated prior to the rule that applies the percentage coupon to the item. Give that a shot and leave me a comment if it doesn't work.